# Could color be a fundamental thing about the universe?

Tags: perception

I'm talking about the color that is inside our heads. I'm not talking about wavelengths.

It seems like any attempt to answer the question 'What is color?' or 'How does brain create color?' must involve referring to 'color' itself.

We've assumed in mainstream science that 'color' must be getting produced in our brain by some complex physical process, and yet we have no clue what that physical process is, or how that process achieves the phenomenon of 'vision'.

Any attempt to explain the origin of color using fundamental ideas like 'forces', 'space', 'charge', 'mass', 'time', etc, is paradoxical. Any complex phenomenon which is explained using those ideas is described by 'movement of particles' or 'flow of energy'. We can explain the phenomenon of planet formation using those ideas (because planet formation involves movement of particles or flow of energy wrt time).

But it's easy to see that 'color' is not one such phenomenon. When we question 'How color gets produced?', we're not asking why some particles move in the way they do. This question is not about movement at all.

In the end, asking 'What is vision?' seems just as complicated as like asking 'What is time?' or 'What is mass?'. These are the things which just are. Physics is about exploring the properties of these fundamental things instead of asking why these things exist.

So I'm saying that solving the mystery of color should involve advancing our understanding of fundamentals of Physics itself. I'm surprised that this is not the popular take on this question, because the phenomenon of 'color' is fundamentally different from any other phenomenon we've explained using the standard models of Physics.

Comment: Why ? See [Evolution of human colour vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_human_colour_vision). It is quite debatable that we cannot understand whatb the *perception* of colour is...

Comment: @MauroALLGERANZA I'm not sure how anyone could describe even a primitive form of vision without referring to some kind of mental picture. And that's completely circular because there's no definition of pictures without defining vision first.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The only form of primitive vision we could describe without referring to pictures is where eye receives light and body reacts according to some instructions. But that kind of vision does not involve any concept of color.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the "fundamental": we can imagine B/W vision; many mammals do not see three fundamental colors. This means that the universe is colorless (mass and energy it is enough) and **we** perceive colors due to the contingent way our eye has evolved. We can understand (more or less) the physical process and the evolution one. There is still a "deep reason" behind that ? Maybe... maybe not.

Comment: "Any attempt to explain the origin of color" ...but there are subjective facts about color; plenty of them.  Yellow is brighter than blue, green is cool, orange is closer to red than it is to green, and so on.  There's at least room for an explanation of color to align with such subjective facts.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not talking about the processing of photons inside our brains (which we do understand). I'm talking about the color, which is the end product of that process. We haven't made any progress in explaining that beyond circular answers or hand-wavy explanations. The fact that color does not exist in the outside world and is not objective has nothing to do with this. The fact that living things have this 'color' experience which even modern science is clueless about means modern physics is enough to describe the outside world, but living things obey some yet undiscovered Physics

Comment: Those are giant qualifiers: "haven't made any progress", "circular answers", "hand-wavy explanations", "clueless".  What then is trichromaticity?  Chromaticity diagrams and advanced color models such as LAB?  Color opponency?  None of these things are describing frequencies of photons per se... what sort of phenomena do you think they describe?

Comment: @HWalters Can we linguistically distinguish between the perception of light and the perception of sound using our current theories ? If not, then we still have made literally zero progress in the question I'm asking. This question is not about the amount of progress we've made in explaining the processing of electrical signals inside our brains. The question is about the progress made in describing what happens between that processing and the actual result that we experience. This is called explanatory gap

Comment: If we have any account at all for color, then by definition that's more than zero.  Also you didn't answer the question.  What is that stuff about if it's not about color?  It's certainly not about photon frequencies.

Comment: @HWalters None of the theories you named even talk about 'what is color?'. Yeah, if we assume that there is a thing called color, then we are able to study relationships among colors. But none of these theories have any answer to 'what IS vision?' other than 'it is a .....thing'. If our modern theories are able to describe that 'thing' even the tiniest bit, then can you describe the answer to the question 'What's the difference between the 'thing' for light and the 'thing' for sound?'

Comment: You're too busy dismissing to notice that you're tripping over yourself.  Back to your qualifiers: => "other than" <= that's an exception qualifier denoting something not nothing.  "any answer to 'what IS vision'" <= the subject is color, not vision.  Vision also has spatial information... but things that _are_ spatially close _look_ spatially close.  But along that manner, colors that _are_ close in LAB _look_ close; and colors that differ in a particular "direction" (e.g. "redder") in LAB _look_ different in that direction (redder).  So that _is_ something.

Comment: ...that's my point; you're here asking a question, and that's fair.  But in doing so, if you're going to be so dismissive that you don't recognize actual answers to the question you're asking when you trip over them, then what's the point in an answer?  It's quite fair to say we don't have a complete account of color.  But it's not fair to say that what we have says nothing about it.  Quibbling about how much this does have is one thing, but calling something nothing is going too far.  If you're going to bother asking the question here, you should be judging these things fairly.

Comment: @HWalters If you look at my question, it's all about 'what IS color/vision?'. It's different from "Assume there's a thing called vision, and study how it behaves wrt changes in the brain". We sure have made progress on the latter. But for the former, we have made zero progress except 'It is a thing'. If you carefully analyze the exception there, you'd see that 'A thing is basically meant to be anything which exists'. Well, of course, color exists. Beinh able to say nothing else but 'It is a thing' is zero progress.

Comment: @HWalters "colors that are close in LAB look close; and colors that differ in a particular "direction" (e.g. "redder") in LAB look different in that direction (redder). So that is something". But that's still about assuming there's a thing called color, and studying how they relate to each other. This 'something' is not related to the fundamental queston of 'What IS color?' The LAB establishes that colors are variations of 'black', 'red' and 'blue'. But what even are 'black', 'red', 'blue' if we have no definition of color? Are they just 'something' taken for granted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108692/discussion-between-h-walters-and-ryder-rude).

Answer (score 4):

We have scientific understanding of a lot that is relevant to color perception, not only wavelengths but also of photoreceptors, how they relate to [color blindness](https://www.color-blindness.com/types-of-color-blindness/), etc.  But the *subjective experience* of color perception is perhaps the most common example used when talking about [qualia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia), the *what it is like* of an experience.  There are various arguments as for why qualia would be non-physical, such as one based on the [inverted spectrum scenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_spectrum), which indeed is also about color.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of philosophy out there about colour perception. It's a big topic. So I will limit myself to a few remarks.

I would follow The Private Language Argument, to say the 'qualia' of colour is essentially meaningless, what matters is the accurate use of linguistic tokens, for generating the mappings behaviour is based on. The source of what you call paradox, is assuming that colour is a single 'kind of thing', when it is really a shortcut for a whole range of narrative groupings - wavelengths, sensations, internal experiences, labels, linguistic tokens.

Consider this account of someone with [proven tetrachromatism](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20140905-the-women-with-super-human-vision), so who experiences 4 primary colours. She describes her experiences before she was diagnosed as having minimal discrepancies. The same genes can result in 2-cone colour-blindness, and there more discrepancies of mapping are seen - it prevents people qualifying as electricians in the UK, or being on the frontline in the fire service. But the inner difference of experience is rarely discussed, or even noticed.

The idea of colour as purely objective is challenged by [impossible colours](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_color), and a range of [optical illusions](https://slate.com/technology/2013/12/optical-illusion-shades-of-gray.html) show us how much post-processing is done - we can deduce [through modelling](https://www.quantamagazine.org/an-idea-from-physics-helps-ai-see-in-higher-dimensions-20200109/) that this is something like a convolutional neural network, identifying image properties like edges, shade, orientation, volume, and textures, with progressive processing and converging towards a consilient cognitive model. The hyperbolic headline of that may be '[your brain hallucinates your conscious reality](https://youtu.be/lyu7v7nWzfo)', but as Anil Seth here makes clear that is in the context of closely-argued well-evidenced thinking about perception. Even Donald Hoffman's work on why [we cannot rely on evolution to give us accurate perceptions](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-evolutionary-argument-against-reality-20160421/) accepts that tools like reasoning and consilience can lead us to more accurate cognitive models, even with unreliable inputs.

> "our understanding of fundamentals of Physics itself"

It sounds like you have decided to implicitly assume noumena for phenomena, that you think we can access the thing-in-itself of reality. I think that's misguided, and that the conservation of information in physics converges with the Buddhist idea of no-essences/sunyata, to suggest [nothing is ever truly seperate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net), including observer and observed, noumena and phenomena, ontic and epistemic.

Comment: I know that perception of the color of an object is not unique. But what IS color? What IS vision? The best we can manage so far is hand-wavy or circular answers to these questions. And it's easy to see why. The very nature of this question prohibits any explanation in terms of other fundamental physical phenomena. And that's because vision is fundamental itself. You can say that vision is the brain's best model to make itself understand outside world. But that statement barely comes even infinitesimally close to actually describing what that model is.

Comment: @RyderRude: No. Consider how much of the world doesn't distinguish between blue & green, & are less good at picking out tones. The converse applies where there are more words, and a society practices distinguishing. "vision is fundamental itself" In Buddhism they have https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80yatana Mind-spaces occur from feedback between senses & phenomena. I can only guess you are doing the 'qualia are magic' thing, but there is a mind-space expansion using language.

Comment: I am not saying that qualia are magic or metaphysical. Magic is just undiscovered physics after all. It's just that vision is a fundamentally different kind of phenomenon than what standard physical models are designed to explain. Modern Physics laws are limited to explaining the processes which involve the changes in configuration of particles distributed in space over time. Vision is not one such thing. Can you define vision without referring to vision itself?

Comment: The best we can do is saying 'vision is a model' or 'vision is a feedback'. Well then 'hearing' is also a model or feedback. Can we describe what distinguishes the models using language?

Comment: @RyderRude: I really don't understand your points. Everything is inside our heads, where we build a salience landscape, highlighting relevant features, allowing us to act effectively. There isn't one definition of colour, or vision, because they are bundles of related phenomena. What is mass led to the Higgs boson. What is time is key to developing quantum gravity.

Comment: And how is the landscape for sound different from the landscape for light? If we know even the tiniest bit about how those landscapes are produced or what they are, we should be able to answer this question.

Comment: I'd refer again to Buddhist ayatanas: each sense has a 'gate', with a field or realm outside, and a sense inside. As in the case of cultures that distinguish between blue and green (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93green_distinction_in_language) how we approach sensations affects our acuity. We never decouple sensations from mental activity, there is always interaction (& sensory deprevation - > hallucinations). Hearing & touch, also ayatanas. We integrate the data streams in the mental 'global workspace' we call consciousness, seeking consilience, convergence of evidence.

Comment: @RyderRude: Mechanisms: eg 'People blind from birth use visual brain area to improve other senses: Can hear and feel with greater acuity' https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/10/101006131203.htm Roughly, half brain emphasises on providing a self-model, half a world-model; from corpus callosotomies https://www.nature.com/articles/483260a Colour can't be an unmediated personal experience (blue-green example) language mediates, focuses attention, rehearses distinctions. Human visual-magnetoreception is fascinating  https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0211826

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there's a whole history regarding just this question: suppose Mary is a colorblind scientist who knows all the dynamical facts about color. One day, her colorblindness goes away and she finally sees a red apple as red. If intrinsic color facts are elemental, it seems she gains knowledge at this time. On the other hand, this "seeming" requires some atomization of "items of knowledge" such that awareness of qualia can be an individual such item (a counterargument being: in an ethereal way Mary now "knows more" but this kind of "knowledge" is trivial or weak or what).

Comment: It's interesting to look at restoration of sight in adults born blind https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/09/090917115658.htm Colourblindness can't be cured yet, but gene therapy will